# noble BLE module - characteristic.subscribe() hitting error

Tags: node.js

I'm on windows 10, using the asus BT-400.

I've successfully connected to my device, read all characteristics/properties, and written to a characteristic. However, I have a characteristic that I'd like to subscribe to for notifications (I have verified that this characteristic has the notify property), and I'm running into an error.

When I follow the code execution, it looks like within gatt.js at the notify function, I'm getting an op code associated with an error.

```
Gatt.prototype.notify = function(serviceUuid, characteristicUuid, notify) {
  var characteristic = this._characteristics[serviceUuid][characteristicUuid];

  this._queueCommand(this.readByTypeRequest(characteristic.startHandle, characteristic.endHandle, GATT_CLIENT_CHARAC_CFG_UUID), function(data) {
    var opcode = data[0];

    if (opcode === ATT_OP_READ_BY_TYPE_RESP) {
      var type = data[1];
      var handle = data.readUInt16LE(2);
      var value = data.readUInt16LE(4);

      var useNotify = characteristic.properties & 0x10;
      var useIndicate = characteristic.properties & 0x20;

      if (notify) {
        if (useNotify) {
          value |= 0x0001;
        } else if (useIndicate) {
          value |= 0x0002;
        }
      } else {
        if (useNotify) {
          value &= 0xfffe;
        } else if (useIndicate) {
          value &= 0xfffd;
        }
      }

      var valueBuffer = new Buffer(2);
      valueBuffer.writeUInt16LE(value, 0);

      this._queueCommand(this.writeRequest(handle, valueBuffer, false), function(data) {
        var opcode = data[0];

        if (opcode === ATT_OP_WRITE_RESP) {
          this.emit('notify', this._address, serviceUuid, characteristicUuid, notify);
        }
      }.bind(this));
    }
  }.bind(this));
};
```

The value of "data" in the callback is: { 1, 8, 54, 0, 10 }.

Also, here is the characteristic I'm calling this on:

```
Characteristic
descriptors: null
name: null
properties: (5) ["read", "writeWithoutResponse", "write", "notify", "indicate"]
type: null
uuid: "495353431e4d4bd9ba6123c647249616"
_events: {data: ƒ}
_eventsCount: 1
_noble: Noble {initialized: true, address: "5c:f3:70:94:4b:01", _state: "poweredOn", _bindings: NobleBindings, _peripherals: {…}, …}
_peripheralId: "3481f4141bf0"
_serviceUuid: "49535343fe7d4ae58fa99fafd205e455"
__proto__: EventEmitter
```

And when I call discoverDescriptors on this characteristic:

```
Descriptor {
  _noble:
   Noble {
     initialized: true,
     address: '5c:f3:70:94:4b:01',
     _state: 'poweredOn',
     _bindings:
      NobleBindings {
        _state: 'poweredOn',
        _addresses: [Object],
        _addresseTypes: [Object],
        _connectable: [Object],
        _pendingConnectionUuid: null,
        _connectionQueue: [],
        _handles: [Object],
        _gatts: [Object],
        _aclStreams: [Object],
        _signalings: [Object],
        _hci: [Hci],
        _gap: [Gap],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 21,
        onSigIntBinded: [Function: bound ],
        _scanServiceUuids: [] },
     _peripherals:
      { '574d3263441d': [Peripheral], '3481f4141bf0': [Peripheral] },
     _services: { '574d3263441d': {}, '3481f4141bf0': [Object] },
     _characteristics: { '574d3263441d': {}, '3481f4141bf0': [Object] },
     _descriptors: { '574d3263441d': {}, '3481f4141bf0': [Object] },
     _discoveredPeripheralUUids: [ '574d3263441d', '3481f4141bf0' ],
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        warning: [Function: bound ],
        newListener: [Function: bound ],
        stateChange: [Function],
        discover: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 4,
     _allowDuplicates: undefined },
  _peripheralId: '3481f4141bf0',
  _serviceUuid: '49535343fe7d4ae58fa99fafd205e455',
  _characteristicUuid: '495353431e4d4bd9ba6123c647249616',
  uuid: '2902',
  name: 'Client Characteristic Configuration',
  type:
   'org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration' }
```

I'm not sure how to interpret the data that's passed back in order to debug this issue further.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is an ATT Response.
1: opcode for Error Response
8: opcode for the request that failed (Read By Type Request with the CCCD uuid)
54 00: search from handle
10: the error code "Attribute Not Found"

So I guess the Client Characteristic Configuration Descriptor is missing for the characteristic.

Comment: I edited my post to include info from the debugger on the characteristic, at the time of the call to ".subscribe()". I looked at the characteristic which I can successfully write to and it appears that the same fields (descriptors, name, type) show up as null, but I can indeed write to that characteristic.

Comment: It seems like the peripheral's GATT db is incorrectly created. It declares both notify and indicate in the characteristic declaration, but then it has no descriptors. That is in violation with the GATT Bluetooth spec.

Comment: So if I connect to the peripheral with nRF connect on my phone, it does show a descriptor: "Client Characteristic Configuration, UUID: 0x2902, Value: Notifications and indications disabled". If I enable notifications through nRF connect, that value changes to "Notifications enabled". Do I need to call characteristic.discoverDescriptors() before trying to subscribe to notifications?

Comment: Edited my post to include the result of discoverDescriptors() on the characteristic.

Comment: Can you run "btmon" in a separate terminal and then start your program that first discovers the characteristics and descriptors and then perform your subscribe code which fails? Then post the full log output from btmon here.

Comment: I'm on Windows so I don't have access to btmon. I am trying to search around for an equivalent. Now I did run "discoverDescriptors()" and in my console the characteristic now shows the relevant descriptor rather than "null" for the characteristic I'm trying to subscribe to, however I'm still getting the same { 1, 8, 54, 0, 10 }.

Comment: You can use Wireshark together with USBPcap. But what Bluetooth stack does the peripheral run? I must say that noble doesn't follow the GATT standard how to read Descriptors. According to the standard, it should be read using ATT Read Request while noble uses ATT Read By Type Request. Maybe the peripheral Bluetooth stack doesn't allow that.

Comment: The peripheral is a custom PCB with a Microchip RN4678 module. The GATT server hosts the "Microchip Transparent UART Service". The module's datasheet doesn't actually have a whole lot of information on the GATT implementation -- I had to grab information off of a tutorial on the Microchip site for a different module: https://microchipdeveloper.com/wireless:ble-mchp-transparent-uart-service

Comment: Did you try the built-in BLE libraries for Windows instead, which is a more mature Bluetooth stack than noble?

Comment: I have not -- noble seemed easier to get up and running with, but if I can't get it to work that all goes out the window. Looks like I will need to switch. Thank you for all of the help!